# Elasticsearch - nested unknown mapping properties - set default type

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm wondering if there is a way to set all nested field to a specific type

The main reason I'm looking for something like that is because the attributes inside category are not not known and can vary.

That's the mapping I have, and every single property must have its type explicitly set:

```
PUT data
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {      
      "category": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "mode": {
            "type":   "text",
            "analyzer": "keyword"
          },
          "sequence": {
            "type":   "text",
            "analyzer": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm looking for something like this **pseudo mapping** below:

```
PUT data
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {      
      "category": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties.*": {
            "type":   "text",
            "analyzer": "keyword"              
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Maybe this is not the way to go and if you have any other solution to handle these dynamic attributes, it will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html)

```
PUT data
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "category_fields": {
          "path_match":   "category.*",
          "mapping": {
            "type":   "text",
            "analyzer": "keyword"              
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "properties": {
    "category": {
      "type": "nested"
    }
  }
}
```